# How to disable new spacing when right clicking in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I guess Chrome updated silently and now whenever I right-click the menu that pops up is gigantic with the extra spacing.

[image]

It isn't the same when right-clicking on the desktop.

How can I disable this "feature"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on the Google forums luckily.

Here's the fix:

Go to the properties of your Chrome shortcut and at the end of the target line add a space then

```
--disable-new-menu-style
```

Make sure you restart Chrome after you add the line.

Comment: This switch doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

In case if mastergalen was confusing at all (I couldn't find the "properties of your chrome" shortcut)

http://www.ghacks.net/2013/03/12/how-to-disable-google-chromes-white-context-menu/

Good luck!

Comment: Add the info from the link here in your own words. Link-only answers are frowned upon, since links often break or the source may disappear. In any case though this question is a duplicate and will be closed as such.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. [More about link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info).